# cannot remove index information from float64 object

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, logical-operators

I would like to do some statistical process on the data based on conditions. But I'm keep getting this error at the `if statement` stage below and I think most likely it happens because of I cannot access to the values in a float object `Q11`.

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. ?Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'patient': [242, 151, 111,122, 342],
        'obs': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
        'treatment': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        'score': ['strong', 'weak', 'weak', 'weak', 'strong']}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['patient', 'obs', 'treatment', 'score'])

#print(df)



     patient  obs  treatment   score
0      242    1          0    strong
1      151    2          1      weak
2      111    3          0      weak
3      122    1          1      weak
4      342    2          0    strong
```

I defined a flow to get some info

```
df_g=df.groupby("score")

veni_vidi = []

for col in df.columns:

    if col=='patient':

        Q11 = df_g[col].transform(lambda group: np.percentile(group, q=25))

        Q11.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True) #trying to drop index from here but it seems not working!

        for val in df[col]:



            if val < Q11:  #This is giving error because of index I guess
                veni_vidi.append('veni')

            else:
                veni_vidi.append('vici')
```

I tried to get rid of index by doing;

```
Q11.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)

0    267.0
1    116.5
2    116.5
3    116.5
4    267.0
Name: patient, dtype: float64
```

but cannot solve the problem.

Thx in advance!

Comment: No, it's giving you an error because `Q11` is a Series. What does it mean for `242` to be less than an entire Series?

Comment: But this seems like an X/Y problem? What is the manipulation you need to achieve? There's almost certainly a better way to remove the loops and do what you need with more concise pandas functions.

Comment: @ALollz `242` just a number no special meaning. This is just a reproducible example to define the problem.

Comment: @ALollz I try to add that `veni_vidi` in to the original data frame and before that I need to do logical operation to define it. I need to keep the loops for sake of problem.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but re-read what I wrote. On the line that throws the error, your syntax `val < Q11` is **literally** asking, is the number `242` less than the Series `Q11`. You're not checking numbers against numbers, you're checking a single number against an **entire** series, and expect a **single** truth value. This is ambiguous, should it be True if it's always True, or True at least once?

Comment: @ALollz Yes, but I'm doing `for val in df[col]` and should be checking each values in patient one by one right ?

Comment: @ALollz Another reason of the error could be `df_g=df.groupby("score")` because If I don't do group by it works with no problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can fix it by using `np.where`

```
df_g=df.groupby("score")

veni_vidi = []

for col in df.columns:

    if col=='patient':

        Q11 = df_g[col].transform(lambda group: np.percentile(group, q=25))


        for val in df[col]:

            veni_vidi.append(np.where(val < Q11,'veni','vici'))
```